# How can I extract data automatically on day to day bases

Tags: unix, automation, server

There is a unix server from which I have to manually extract data  from a particular file  on DAY TO DAY bases.
As it is really time consuming so was wondering if there is any chance to automate this thing ??
Please provide advise as I really need to automate this day to day task.

Actually I am extracting data and saving that data I to file and sending over the email. So the thing is I want to generate a shell script which will extract the data on a particular time duration , and the extracted data will be send via email.And sending the data over the email can be done via Unix command. So my question is what configuration we need to do on server so this task can be automated

Regards

Comment: We need way more details to help you. What is the issue? Where are you extracting them to? How do you want to extract? How do you want to automate it?

Comment: Actually I am extracting data and saving that data I to file and sending over the email. So the thing is I want to generate a shell script which will extract the data on a particular time duration , and the extracted data will be send via email.And sending the data over the email can be done via Unix command. So my question is what configuration we need to do on server so this task can be automated

Comment: Okay. That should be in the question, please edit it to include that info. You want to extract an arbitrary number of compressed files based on a time schedule and email them? For scheduling, try using cron.

Comment: Apart from scheduling part is it possible to create script on the another server let's say A and the running bash script on server  A to get data extracted from server B (when actual data is present)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand your goal, you can use [cron](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) to schedule tasks to run on either host.

As for how to transfer the file, you can make it happen using a single unix command. I use `scp` to transfer files, which you can use like the following, if you run the command from the host without the file: `scp username@serverB:/path/to/file /desired/file/path/on/serverA`

As for what to use with a cronjob, you want this job to run once a day, every day. So, you would have a job looking like so: `0 1 * * * scp username@serverB:/path/to/file /desired/file/path/on/serverA`

Which should run the scp command every day at 1 am.

A few more links to help with cron:

http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/
http://www.ghacks.net/2009/01/11/using-cron-to-automate-linux-tasks/